# Fixture error in Minitest: table has no column named X

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I'm hitting a wall trying to set up tests for my `user_tests` model.

The error (one example of many) I get when running the tests (minitest):

```
ERROR["test_should_get_new", Admin::TestConfigsControllerTest, 2016-01-07 13:04:02 +0100]
test_should_get_new#Admin::TestConfigsControllerTest (1452168242.12s)
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError:
     ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table "user_tests" has no column named "user".
```

It's correct that there is no column named `user`, but there is a `user_id` and in other fixtures, this is working correctly. What is wrong with my setup that for this model the columns can't be found?

The fixture `user_tests.yml`:

```
user_test_one:
  started: false
  started_at:
  finished: false
  finished_at:
  invited: true
  invited_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
  user: michael
  test_config: test_config_one
  test_result:
  test_result_type:

user_test_two:
  started: false
  started_at:
  finished: false
  finished_at:
  test_result:
  test_result_type:
  invited: false
  invited_at:
  user: michael
  test_config: test_config_two
  test_result:
  test_result_type:
```

Here both `user`, `test_config` and `test_result` should point to columns `user_id`, `test_config_id` and `test_result_id`. All give the same type of errors.

It works fine for `users.yml` where both company and user_group are links to other tables (shout out to Michael Hartle for the excellent Ruby on Rails Tutorial):

```
michael:
  first_name: Michael
  last_name: Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  admin: true
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
  company: my-company
  user_group: my-company-groep

archer:
  first_name: Sterling
  last_name: Archer
  email: duchess@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
  company: my-company
  user_group: my-company-groep
```

The first lines from the `users_test.rb` model:

```
class UserTest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, required: true
  belongs_to :test_config, required: true
  belongs_to :test_result, polymorphic: true
  attr_accessor :step, :send_invitation
```

Can't find anything wrong with the database either. Here's a screenshot of both the `users` and `user_tests` tables in SQLite:

[image: SQLlite tables]

Any thoughts?

**Update**: It must have something to do with the test not finding the model `user_test.rb` for this fixture (`user_tests.yml`). I can convert the columns `user` and `test_config` to include `_id` but then an error occurs that the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns may not be nil (`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: user_tests.created_at`). Those should be handled by Rails, but aren't. Why?

```
user_test_one:
  started: false
  started_at:
  finished: false
  finished_at:
  invited: true
  invited_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
  test_config_id: 1
  user_id: 1
  created_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
  updated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
```

**Update 2**: I've got a strong suspicion the problem is caused by including "Test" in the model/table name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renaming the table and all corresponding code from `user_test` (and all variants) to `user_survey` solved the problem.